# executing the content of a string in c

Tags: c, linux, string, assembly, segmentation-fault

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

char code[] ="\x52\x56\x57\x50\xB8\x41\x00\x00\x00\x50\xB8\x01\x00\x00\x00\xBF\x01\x00\x00\x00\x48\x89\xE6\xBA\x01\x00\x00\x00\x0F\x05\x58\x58\x5F\x5E\x5A\xC3";

int main(){
    void(*func)() = (void (*)())code;
    (*func)();
    return 0 ;
    
}
```

what I have here is a string which stores a binary code to print a character ('A') , I pass it as a function pointer to func , than i try to execute it .
the output :

```
$ ./test
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

this is the assembly code :

```
0:  52                      push   rdx
1:  56                      push   rsi
2:  57                      push   rdi
3:  50                      push   rax
4:  b8 41 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x41
9:  50                      push   rax
a:  b8 01 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x1
f:  bf 01 00 00 00          mov    edi,0x1
14: 48 89 e6                mov    rsi,rsp
17: ba 01 00 00 00          mov    edx,0x1
1c: 0f 05                   syscall
1e: 58                      pop    rax
1f: 58                      pop    rax
20: 5f                      pop    rdi
21: 5e                      pop    rsi
22: 5a                      pop    rdx
23: c3                      ret
```

Comment: Data is not executable by default.

Comment: You probbaly don't have execute permission for the data segment.

Comment: You can try `gcc -z execstack`.

Comment: This is operating system specific. For Linux, see [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), notably [mmap(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html), [mprotect(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mprotect.2.html), [execve(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) also see [pmap(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pmap.1.html) and [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) and of course read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/).

Comment: thank you all , the ``gcc -z execstack`` solved the problem for me

Comment: Don't forget to read the documentation of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and of [binutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As pointed out by @WeatherVane, you need permission to execute a data segment, [mprotect](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mprotect.2.html) can help:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdint.h>

static char code[] = "\x52\x56\x57\x50\xB8\x41\x00\x00\x00\x50\xB8\x01\x00\x00"
                     "\x00\xBF\x01\x00\x00\x00\x48\x89\xE6\xBA\x01\x00\x00\x00"
                     "\x0F\x05\x58\x58\x5F\x5E\x5A\xC3";
                                 
int main(void)
{
    uintptr_t page = (uintptr_t)code & -4095ULL;

    mprotect((void *)page, 4096, PROT_READ | PROT_EXEC | PROT_WRITE);

    void (*func)(void) = (void (*)(void))code;

    func();
    return 0;
}
```

You can see the result (`A`) in [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Y4qjPo)